# I can't get my desktop push notification for chrome extension to open in the same tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications, push-notification, desktop

Once I click the view product button I created on the notification, the link opens in a new tab but for a second notification, the link opens two similar tabs and it goes on.
The tabs keep increasing as the notifications increase.
It is an ecommerce website

Here's my code. I don't know where I went wrong.

```
var messages = [] ;
var ids = [] ;

var latestItem;


$(function(){
engine();
    setInterval(engine, 60000);
}); 

function engine(){
    var newItems = [];
        $.get('https://www.mysite.or/electronics-video/', function(data){
            var htmlData = data;

            $data = ($(htmlData).find('.offer').eq(0));
            $data.find('.fleft').remove();

            $data.find('.rel.observelinkinfo.inlblk.zi3').remove();
            $data.find('.suggesttitleright.small.top.abs.zi2.br4.hidden').remove();
            $data.find('.thumb.vtop.inlblk.rel.tdnone.linkWithHash.scale4.detailsLink').remove();
            $data.find('.color-9.lheight16.margintop5').remove();
            $data.find('.breadcrumb.x-normal').remove();
            $data.find('.normal.inlblk.pdingtop5.lheight16.color.2').remove();


        $('body').append($data);

        for(i = 0; i<$data.find('h3.x-large.lheight20.margintop5').length; i++){

            ids[i]=($($data).find('td.wwnormal.tright.td-price').eq(i).find('p.price').text()).replace(/\n\r/g, '').trim();
            messages[i]= ($($data).find('h3.x-large.lheight20.margintop5').eq(i).find('a.marginright5.link.linkWithHash.detailsLink').text()).replace(/\n\r/g, '').trim();

        }


if (latestItem == ids[0]) {

    }else if(latestItem === undefined) {
        var firstRun = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "Site Notifier",
            message: 'Visit the website for updates on new products',
            iconUrl: "origi.png"
        }


        chrome.notifications.create(firstRun);
        latestItem = ids[0];

    }else if(latestItem != ids[0]) {
        for(j = 0; j<ids.length; j++){
            if(latestItem == ids[j]){
                break;
            }else{
                if (messages[j] != " "){
                newItems[j]= messages[j].concat(" - ").concat(ids[j]);
            }
        }

    }
        latestItem = ids[0];
    }
        if (newItems.length == 0){


        }else{
            for(i=0;i<newItems.length; i++){
        var myItem = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "New Product Alert!",
            message: newItems[i],
            contextMessage: "Site Notifier",
            buttons: [{
                title: "View Product"

            }],
            iconUrl: "origi.png"
        };

        chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(){
            window.open('https://www.mysite.or/electronics-video/');


        });

        chrome.notifications.create(myItem);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function (notificationId, buttonIndex) {
    if (notificationId == '1234567' && buttonIndex == 0) {
        var $ismysite = false;
        chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function (windows) {
            windows.forEach(function (window) {
                window.tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
                    if (tab.url.toString().lastIndexOf('mysite') > -1) {
                        $ismysite= true
                    }
                });
            });
            if (!$ismysite) {
                $ismysite = false;
                chrome.tabs.create({ url: "YourSire" }, function () {
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, at the end `if (newItems.length == 0)`
`else` statement will create notification for every element of *newItems* array **AND** it will add `onClicked` listener.
You need to pull out

```
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(){
  window.open('https://www.mysite.or/electronics-video/');
});
```

somewhere out of that loop.
If you need to know which notification is clicked, you can find out by ID in callback. For that you probably need to maintain some ID - url connection in global object.

Comment: It's been really a problem, don't know what you me by pull out

Comment: @CollinKiprono every time you loop trough your **newItems** array, you are adding **onButtonClicked** listener and they are multiplying. You need to add that listener only once somewhere out of that loop

Comment: I really get what your saying but tried working the listener out of the loop but it the tabs keep increasing. There's definitely something I'm doing wrong. I just can't figure it out